Practicality of poison made with Minor Creation
For making poisons (for free), Minor Creation have been suggested in numeros threads over Minmax, Giantitp forums or even there.
I have never seen a complete answer or a practical one.
Let's say you want to use your minor creation spell / power or spell-like ability (Via the Making dragonmark) to make poisons.
You made a list of potential poisons that are nonmagical, unattended object of nonliving, vegetable matter.
What happens?
Do you need to make a craft DC? "Maybe" is the general answer.
But do you? In the craft profession, an item is listed as complex from DC20. Does that mean you do need to make a craft check only is your poison require a DC20 or higher to be crafted?
When and if you happen to craft your poison... So what? It spawns right in front of you. How do you use it, how do you store it? The spell is silent and so are many people talking about this situation.
Do you need to bring enough flask/container with you to store all these cubic square of non-living matter?
If you craft your poison, does it come for free? Do you have to spend 1/6 of the price to craft it? But then you'd need 8 hours to craft the poison and that would render the operation useless since your poison would disappear soon after unless you have a spellcaster level of 8+.
Or does the crafting skill check from the spell prevent you from having to use the craft rule? You just pass the check and boom, all your poison is there, sitting right before you, ready to be used?
I am really interested by poison in this game and always wanted to use them and I have been curious about the Minor Creation solution for a while but never found a clear answer on how it is supposed to work.
My final goal is to be able to cast/use minor creation and use the poison as is.

Minor creation says it creates an object that is made of nonliving vegetable matter. It says nothing about needing it to be a simple object, nor does it say you are the one making it—the spell is. So no, as written, you do not need a Craft check, you do not require materials, and it can produce an object that would require a Craft check if you made it.
Exactly what “object” entails—whether a “vat of poison” is a single object or two (the vat and the poison in it) is unclear, and up to the DM. Providing a container is not a terribly significant problem, if you should want one (or need one, depending on how the DM interprets Conjuration’s requirement of a “surface capable of supporting [a conjured object]”). The quantity can be—which is why many recommend shrink item to go along with minor creation. Or you just parcel out the poison into individual vials, though you’ll need another DM ruling on how long that takes and/or whether there’s any risk of poisoning yourself while you do it.
Also, probably the most popular use of minor creation is for black lotus extract, which is a contact poison. You can literally just conjure cubic feet of that and let it flood out among your enemies. Casting takes a minute, so you can only use this maneuver from hiding, but it can still be pretty devastating (depending on exactly how your DM rules it, since as far as I know, there aren’t rules for being subjected to many simultaneous doses like that).
So yes, there are a number of points that are unclear and need DM adjudication. But pretty much no matter what, unless the DM outright houserules things, the combination is extremely powerful, and arguably broken.

Better solution than Lotos Extract: a cubic foot of Foxglove extract or similar over the food kettle is a few hundred thousand doses, enough to kill a town by 1d6 Constitution Damage per dose... See for example: James Lowder et al.: Ravenloft Gazetteer Vol.IV., sine loco (2003), pp. 132–133.

@Trish Sure, but black lotus extract is the one you always see people suggesting in forum discussions and so on; this is the first I’ve heard foxglove mentioned. Since the question is about those “numeros [sic] threads,” that’s what I was speaking to.

probably because the Ravenloft Gazetter is from Ravenloft, and not main D&D, though officially licensed and all the shebang.

Is the Ravenloft Gazetter published by WotC, making it first party? There is the Logo and all but it seems to be a Sword & Sorcery D20 product.

@Ednoc WotC didn’t publish anything for Ravenloft for 3.5e, but they did license it to other people who were allowed to call theirs the “official” 3.5e Ravenloft implementation. Some of it (3.0e book) is okay; other bits (3.5e Player’s Guide) are... less so. Anyway, if you’re not playing in Ravenloft to begin with, you probably shouldn’t have any expectation of being allowed that source.

@Ednoc The Gazetter in particular carries the Arthaus brand, which means the writers behind it were White Wolf. But, it was an officially, fully licensed product. But indeed, unless you play Ravenloft, looking for other poisons would be a good idea.
